# Change SMOTE parameters inside CARET k-fold cross-validation classification

Tags: r, classification, r-caret

I have a classification problem with a very skewed class to predict (e.g. 90% / 10% unbalanced binary variable to predict).

In order to deal with that issue, I want to use the SMOTE method to oversample this class variable. However, as I read here (http://www.marcoaltini.com/blog/dealing-with-imbalanced-data-undersampling-oversampling-and-proper-cross-validation) it is best practice to use SMOTE inside the k-fold loop to avoid overfitting.

As I'm using the caret package to perform my analysis, I'm referring to this link (http://topepo.github.io/caret/sampling.html). I undestand everything perfectly but the last part where it explains how to change the SMOTE parameters:

```
smotest <- list(name = "SMOTE with more neighbors!",
            func = function (x, y) {
              library(DMwR)
              dat <- if (is.data.frame(x)) x else as.data.frame(x)
              dat$.y <- y
              dat <- SMOTE(.y ~ ., data = dat, k = 10)
              list(x = dat[, !grepl(".y", colnames(dat), fixed = TRUE)],
                   y = dat$.y)
              },
            first = TRUE)
```

I simply don't understand this. Someone care to explain? Let's say I want to include the SMOTE parameters perc.over, k and perc.under, how would I do that?

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

Actually I realized I could probably just add these parameters inside the "SMOTE" expression in the above function, this would for instance give something like:

```
smotest <- list(name = "SMOTE with more neighbors!",
            func = function (x, y) {
              library(DMwR)
              dat <- if (is.data.frame(x)) x else as.data.frame(x)
              dat$.y <- y
              dat <- SMOTE(.y ~ ., data = dat, k = 10, perc.over = 1200, perc.under = 100)
              list(x = dat[, !grepl(".y", colnames(dat), fixed = TRUE)],
                   y = dat$.y)
              },
            first = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure to have understood what you do not understand but here is an attempt to clarify what is done in this piece of code.

The `smotest` object is created as list because it is the way the argument `sampling` of `trainControl` function must be represented. The first element of this list is a `name` used only for display purposes. The second, `func`, is the actual sampling function. The third, `first`, is a logical value indicating whether samplin must be done before or after the pre-processing step.

The element `func` is here only a wrapper of `SMOTE` function. In this wrapper, line 3 is here because only a `data.frame` can be passed to `SMOTE` function. Line 4 is added because a `formula` combined to a `data.frame` is used in `SMOTE` rather than a couple `x` `y`. Line 6 is here to ensure that the appropriate format is returned to `trainControl`.

And, to answer you last question: **yes**, you can do what you have proposed to set additional parameters to `SMOTE`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, when I try what I posted above, i.e. adding parameters, it returns an error "Error in parse_sampling(trControl$sampling) : 
  That sampling scheme is not in caret's built-in library". However when I try without these new parameters, it works.

Comment: Weird... Because this error should prompt only if sampling argument given to trainControl is a character...

Comment: I think I just realized my  mistake. I forgot to clean variables in my train dataset that I don't input in the model, reason I have text variables for example. Thank you for making me realize that !

Comment: I would add something that might be obvious to some, but I spent a while looking for it. Once created the wrapper function (for example: smotest), it has to be passed to the argument sampling in trainControl substituting "smote" without quotes like this: trainControl(sampling=smotest) instead of trainControl(sampling="smote")